# Install Ambari, can't download hortonworks HDP from amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, ambari

I'm tring to install apache ambari on my wsl(ubuntu 20.04) as the [Ambari User Guides](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.5) step by step.  while install and packing the project to deb files use command:

`mvn -B clean install jdeb:jdeb -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0 -DbuildNumber=5895e4ed6b30a2da8a90fee2403b6cab91d19972 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.6"` .

got this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) on project ambari-metrics-timelineservice: An Ant BuildException has occured: Can't get https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.0-315/tars/hbase/hbase-2.0.2.3.1.4.0-315-bin.tar.gz to /root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-timelineservice/target/embedded/hbase.tar.gz
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<get usetimestamp="true" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.0-315/tars/hbase/hbase-2.0.2.3.1.4.0-315-bin.tar.gz" dest="/root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-timelineservice/target/embedded/hbase.tar.gz"/>... @ 5:273 in /root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-timelineservice/target/antrun/build-Download HBase.xml
```

**apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-metrics/pom.xml** defined the nortonworks HDP sources:

```
<hbase.tar>http://dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.0.0.0-1634/tars/hbase/hbase-2.0.0.3.0.0.0-1634-bin.tar.gz</hbase.tar>
<hbase.folder>hbase-2.0.0.3.0.0.0-1634</hbase.folder>
<hadoop.tar>http://dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.0.0.0-1634/tars/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634.tar.gz</hadoop.tar>
<hadoop.folder>hadoop-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634</hadoop.folder>
<phoenix.tar>http://dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.0.0.0-1634/tars/phoenix/phoenix-5.0.0.3.0.0.0-1634.tar.gz</phoenix.tar>
<phoenix.folder>phoenix-5.0.0.3.0.0.0-1634</phoenix.folder>
```

I tried to download official Hbase-2.3.2, Hadoop-3.3.0,phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0 to instead hotonworks HDP, but failed and got an other error.

I tried to download hortonworks HDP directly use wget and got:

```
Resolving dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com (dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.217.40.204
Connecting to dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com 
(dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com)|52.217.40.204|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
```

where/how can i download these hortonworks HDP files and continue to install ambari?

Comment: Work in progress:  https://github.com/apache/ambari/pull/3283

Answer (score 1):

This solution from the Apache Ambari team fixed this and other similar issues with HDP urls: https://github.com/apache/ambari/pull/3283

You need to make the corresponding code changes: https://github.com/apache/ambari/pull/3283/commits/3dca705f831383274a78a8c981ac2b12e2ecce85

Answer (score 0):

replace  the  downlink  with

```
 <hbase.tar>https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.1-1/tars/hbase/hbase-2.0.2.3.1.4.1-1-bin.tar.gz</hbase.tar>
    <hbase.tar>https://private-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/updates/3.1.4.1-1/tars/hbase/hbase-2.0.2.3.1.4.1-1-bin.tar.gz</hbase.tar>
    <hbase.folder>hbase-2.0.2.3.1.4.1-1</hbase.folder>
    <hadoop.tar>https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.1-1/tars/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.1.3.1.4.1-1.tar.gz</hadoop.tar>
    <hadoop.tar>https://private-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/updates/3.1.4.1-1/tars/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.1.3.1.4.1-1.tar.gz</hadoop.tar>
    <hadoop.folder>hadoop-3.1.1.3.1.4.1-1</hadoop.folder>
    <grafana.folder>grafana-6.4.2</grafana.folder>
    <grafana.tar>https://dl.grafana.com/oss/release/grafana-6.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz</grafana.tar>
    <phoenix.tar>https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.1-1/tars/phoenix/phoenix-5.0.0.3.1.4.1-1.tar.gz</phoenix.tar>
    <phoenix.tar>https://private-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/updates/3.1.4.1-1/tars/phoenix/phoenix-5.0.0.3.1.4.1-1.tar.gz</phoenix.tar>
    <phoenix.folder>phoenix-5.0.0.3.1.4.1-1</phoenix.folder>
```

Answer (score 0):

edit file `ambari-metrics/pom.xml` and replace download link, for example I changed

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.0-315/tars/hbase/hbase-2.0.2.3.1.4.0-315-bin.tar.gz
```

for

```
https://downloads.apache.org/hbase/2.3.5/hbase-2.3.5-src.tar.gz
```