# ambari build failed because of unreachable hortonworks repositories

Tags: ambari

As Cloudera closes all public repositories for ambari (see https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hortonworks-Repositories-can-t-be-accessed/td-p/311058) I tried to build ambari from scratch by my self (see [Ambari 2.7.5 Installation Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.5)

I struggled with the problem described in [Install Ambari, can't download hortonworks HDP from amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494636/install-ambari-cant-download-hortonworks-hdp-from-amazon-s3)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) on project ambari-metrics-timelineservice: An Ant BuildException has occured: Can't get https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonwo
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<get usetimestamp="true" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.1-1/tars/hbase/hbase-2.0.2.3.1.4.1-1-bin.tar.gz" dest="/home/...
```

But the suggested solution does work for me. It turns out that the repositories  https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP seem to be closed too.

Is there any chance to build ambari at the moment?
Are there different public repositories to download the binaries but the closed repositories of hortonworks/cloudera?

Answer (score 0):

These configurations solved this problem to me:

**vi ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-timelineservice/pom.xml**

Change:

```
   <hadoop.version>3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315</hadoop.version>
    <phoenix.version>5.0.0.3.1.4.0-315</phoenix.version>
    <hbase.version>2.0.2.3.1.4.0-315</hbase.version>
```

To:

```
<hadoop.version>3.1.1</hadoop.version>
<phoenix.version>5.0.0-HBase-2.0</phoenix.version>
<hbase.version>2.0.2</hbase.version>
```

**vi ambari-metrics/pom.xml**

Change:

```
<hbase.tar>https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.0-315/tars/hbase/hbase-2.0.2.3.1.4.0-315-bin.tar.gz</hbase.tar>
<hbase.folder>hbase-2.0.2.3.1.4.0-315</hbase.folder>
<hadoop.tar>https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.0-315/tars/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315.tar.gz</hadoop.tar>
<hadoop.folder>hadoop-3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315</hadoop.folder>
```

To:

```
<hbase.tar>https://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase/2.0.2/hbase-2.0.2-bin.tar.gz</hbase.tar>
<hbase.folder>hbase-2.0.2</hbase.folder>
<hadoop.tar>https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.1.1/hadoop-3.1.1.tar.gz</hadoop.tar>
<hadoop.folder>hadoop-3.1.1</hadoop.folder>
```

On same file, change:

```
  <phoenix.tar>https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.0-315/tars/phoenix/phoenix-5.0.0.3.1.4.0-315.tar.gz</phoenix.tar>
    <phoenix.folder>phoenix-5.0.0.3.1.4.0-315</phoenix.folder>
```

To:

```
<phoenix.tar>https://downloads.apache.org/phoenix/apache-phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0/bin/apache-phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-bin.tar.gz</phoenix.tar>
<phoenix.folder>apache-phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-bin</phoenix.folder>
```